# Failed installing Ubuntu using termux-ubuntu

Tags: root-access, installation, termux

I want to mine sugar on my Android phone.
Can someone help a simple complete script, especially to complete method 1 or 2, whichever works.

**METHOD 1**

Installed F-Droid and Termux

**Commands**

```
pkg install automake clang git vim
press y to continue

clone git https://github.com/decryp2kanon/sugarmaker
```

When it's done, I enter

```
$ cd sugarmaker/
-/sugarmaker $ ./autogen.sh
```

it says

```
bash:  no such file or directory
```

**METHOD 2**

These two methods I tried each of them on both phones.
On method 2, when I get here, it keeps saying error on Huawei Y Pro phone and Huawei P20 Lite.

```
pkg update
press y to continue

pkg upgrade
press y to continue

pkg install git

pkg install wget
press y to continue

pkg install proot
press y to continue

git clone http://github.com/Neo-oli/termux-ubuntu.get
```

The problem start here on P20 Lite

```
-$ cd termux-ubuntu
-/termux-ubuntu $ ./ubuntu.sh
```

It says decompressing Ubuntu image, but this does not look like a trz archive.

Making start Ubuntu executable. You can now launch Ubuntu with ./start-ubuntu.sh script.

And it shows code 404 like the link to the image is not working also.

Comment: The script you are using is a bit old, it is trying to install Ubuntu 19.04 (Disco Dingo) which is a non-LTS version. Therefore support for this version ended in January 2020 and the download image was removed which makes your installer script useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the [`ubuntu.sh`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Neo-Oli/termux-ubuntu/master/ubuntu.sh), you get an error because the disco image has been removed and the following URL doesn't download anything:

```
https://partner-images.canonical.com/core/disco/current/ubuntu-disco-core-cloudimg-${archurl}-root.tar.gz
```

Check the available images from [this directory](https://partner-images.canonical.com/core/). Edit the `ubuntu.sh` by adding a valid URL. Here is an example using `focal` Codename. Replace the following line:

```
 wget "https://partner-images.canonical.com/core/disco/current/ubuntu-disco-core-cloudimg-${archurl}-root.tar.gz" -O $tarball
```

with:

```
wget "https://partner-images.canonical.com/core/focal/current/ubuntu-focal-core-cloudimg-armhf-root.tar.gz"  -O $tarball
```

or using the `archurl` variable:

```
wget "https://partner-images.canonical.com/core/focal/current/ubuntu-focal-core-cloudimg-${archurl}-root.tar.gz"  -O $tarball
```

Then run your script it should work as expected.